# How to pass different values of a certain column to an aggregate function conditionally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Well the title of this question might not actually reflect what I want, I couldn't think of anything better. Maybe I should've appended a *'and then join two tables acquired this way'* to the end.

Let's say I have this table. The scenario is, we pay loans with id `loan_id`, and we store payments of that in the table "Payment", each payment has its own `id`. When customer pays the payment, we change `paid` to `1`.

```
+---------+----+--------+------+
| loan_id | id | amount | paid |
+---------+----+--------+------+
|       1 |  1 |   1000 |    1 |
|       1 |  2 |   1000 |    1 |
|       1 |  3 |   1000 |    0 |
|       2 |  4 |  10000 |    0 |
|       3 |  5 |  20000 |    1 |
+---------+----+--------+------+
```

And now we need a report on loans. The output should look like this:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+
| loan_id |  paid | remaining |
+---------+-------+-----------+
|       1 |  2000 |      1000 |
|       2 |     0 |     10000 |
|       3 | 20000 |         0 |
+---------+-------+-----------+
```

The `paid` column is basically sum of all `amount` fields where pay = 1. And the `remaining` is sum of the `amount` rows for which pay = 0. They should be grouped by `loan_id`.

### What I tried:

I tried different joins, products, etc but the best thing I could get out of my queries was this one:

```
SELECT loan_id, SUM(paid), SUM(remaining)
FROM (
    SELECT loan_id, 0 AS paid, SUM(amount) AS remaining
    FROM Payment
    WHERE paid = 0
    GROUP BY loan_id

    UNION

    SELECT loan_id, SUM(amount) AS paid, 0 AS remaining
    FROM Payment
    WHERE paid = 1
    GROUP BY loan_id
)
GROUP BY loan_id
```

But I guess there should be better ways than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
loan_id, 
SUM(case when paid = 1 then amount else 0 end) as payed, 
SUM(case when paid = 0 then amount else 0 end) as remaining
FROM Payment
GROUP BY loan_id
```

I would avoid to use a column name as an alias (paid => payed), for code clarity

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT Loan_ID,
SUM(Amount*Paid) Paid,
SUM(Amount*(1-Paid)) Remaining
FROM Payment
GROUP BY Loan_ID
```

Comment: This is a variation of @RaphaëlAlthaus's answer, I upvote it since you used a smart trick.